# How to detect HP Scanjet G2410 Scanner if it is not being detected automatically?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, hp, additional-drivers, simplescan

I have a scanner **HP Scanjet G2410** (Flatbed Style) and I tried connecting it to my **Ubuntu 16.04 LTS** with the hope that my PC will automatically detect it but **'Simple Scan'** application showed a message as *'No scanners detected'*. So I went to Software & Updates  >  Additional Drivers where I selected following option to see if anything works;

[image]

but that did not worked and still I can not use my scanner.

Is there any solution so I can use my scanner?

I used the command `sudo sane-find-scanner` in the terminal and it returned with this output;

[image]

Please help me what I can I do further?

Comment: It seems that scanner [is supported](http://sane-project.org/sane-mfgs.html) by [sane-genesys backend](http://www.sane-project.org/man/sane-genesys.5.html). Try to find it with `sudo sane-find-scanner`.

Comment: Ok I tried what U said and I'm altering my question to let U know what happened, Please check out.

Comment: Seems to be connectivity or power issue. Do you see any blinking/glowing lights/LEDs on scanner? Do you see your scanner in `lsusb` or `tail -f /var/log/syslog` (disconnect it and reconnect to see changes)? Just tested my old Epson 1670 with 16.04 and it works great in xsane.

Comment: No my scanner is not showing in lsusb and I disconnected and reconnected after running the next command but it also not helped. Meanwhile I found 'http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/index.html' this, should I try this?

Comment: I have never tried hplip with separate scanner, but it works great with multifunction HP devices. You can install it from repository with `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui` and try. Have you tried connecting scanner to other USB port or other computer?

Comment: I installed Hplip and the program runs correctly however it is not detecting my scanner. Yes I tried connecting to all other USB ports my PC has.

Comment: I have no more ideas. May be scanner is dead.